# Laptop graphical glitch

Tags: nvidia, graphics, optimus

From time to time, the screen of my laptop will get stuck in a previous position and then suddenly revert back after I press some buttons to force it to update the screen. The problem doesn't appear if I connect it to an external monitor with a usb-c cable. I am extremely paranoid that this will eventually lead me to entering the wrong command in a command prompt. I have the nvidia driver xserver-xorg-video-nvidia/stable,now 525.125.06-1~deb12u1 amd64 [installed].

These are my specs:
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) x86_64
Host: HP ENVY Laptop 13-aq0xxx
Kernel: 6.1.0-12-amd64
Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1080
WM: i3
CPU: Intel i7-8565U (8) @ 4.600GHz
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce MX250
GPU: Intel WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics 620]
Memory: 1845MiB / 7660MiB